# object has no attribute show

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I have installed `wxpython` successfully which i verified by

```
import wx
```

But when I write a code

```
import wx
class gui(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent,id,'Visualisation for Telecom Customer Data', size = (300,200))

if __name__ =='__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = gui(parent = None, id = -1)
    frame.show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

it shows error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Bishnu\BE\4th year\7th semester\Major Project I\Workspace\Wxpython\default\GUI.py", line 13, in <module>
    frame.show()
AttributeError: 'gui' object has no attribute 'show'
```

what may be the solution ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
frame.Show()
```

instead of

```
frame.show()
```

all are case sensitive in python