# wxPython AttribeError: Frame Object has no attribute

Tags: python, wxpython

I am currently following a tutorial on wxPython.org.

On the running second lesson I have received an error stating that the Frame object has no attribute.

I tried to follow the advice given here: 
[wxPython AttributeError: module has no attribute 'Frame'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034572/wxpython-attributeerror-module-has-no-attribute-frame), but I could not find any file with 'wx.py' located on the local system. I did find some Canopy files that were similar in that they had 'wx.py' in the file name. I am wondering if these would interfere despite me not using Canopy.

Is there anything else that I can look at?

System: OSX 10.6.8,
Python 2.7.6,
wxPython 3.0.0, Gedit

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial you are following?

Comment: If you saved the file as `wx.py`, then that would be your issue. But if you saved it in a folder called `wx`, that could also be your issue.

Comment: check here...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230762/object-has-no-attribute-show

Answer (score 0):

Install wxWidgets with these instructions :

Run the configure script:

```
  ./configure --with-gtk
```

Run the make file:

```
  make
```

Install wxGTK:

```
  make install
```

Link the library:

```
  ldconfig
```

You might want to follow these instruction to install wxPython :

Edit the config.py

```
  BUILD_GLCANVAS = 0 # If true, build the contrib/glcanvas extension module
  BUILD_OGL = 0      # If true, build the contrib/ogl extension module
  BUILD_STC = 1      # If true, build the contrib/stc extension module
```

Build the python module (build  with extensions):

```
  python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Install the module:

```
  python setup.py install
```

SETENV variables

```
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
  export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH=<path-to-wxPython-dir>/wxPython
```